# Django formsubmission gives me a 405 error

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to display a form and and take the submission in post of my class-based view.

I am not using Django's form as it breaks my design.

Code for my form:

```
<form action="." method="POST" >
     <input type='hidden' name='pf_id' value='{{pf.id}}' />
     <input type='hidden' name='content_type' value='portfolio' />
     <textarea id="id_comment" name="comment"></textarea>
     <section><input type="submit" value="submit" name="commentSubmit" class="comment-button"  title="submit" class="comment-button" /></section>
</form>
```

In `views.py`:

```
class ProjectDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'account/inner-profile-page.html'
    model = ProjectDetail
    context_object_name = 'project'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(ProjectDetail, title_slug = self.kwargs['title_slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        projects = []
        for st in SubType.objects.all():
            user = self.get_object().user
            pd = ProjectDetail.objects.filter(user=user,project_sub_type__sub_type=st)  
            if pd.count() > 0:
                projects.append((st.name, pd.count()))
        context['projects'] = projects
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

I am expecting the post method to be called when form is submitted (hopefully I am right in my assumption), but it does not, as submitting this form takes me to a blank page. The URL does not change and I get 405 error message in my runserver shell. Why is this happening ?
my urls are like this:

```
url(r'^project-detail/(?P<title_slug>\w+)/$',ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name="project-detail-view"),
url(r'^project-page/(?P<user_slug>.+)/$',projectPage.as_view(),name='projectPage'),
```

Comment: you need to return response for `def post` .

Comment: @PriyankPatel: yet `post` isn't called *at all*.

Comment: Is the form URL the same as  the `ProjectDetailView` URL? e.g. is it `project-detail/some_title/`?

Comment: action seems wrong. shouldn't it be just `""` to post to current page?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with your view. As you have inherited the FormMixin and DetailView neither does implement the POST method and hence django returns 405 error code. Try inheriting an updateview or createview to support post functionality.

Comment: except that he implements `post` in `ProjectDetailView` himself

Comment: but it might make sense to use django.views.generic.UpdateView instead of DetailView - as it also gives you some methods to deal with form processing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use `CreateView` because they are not dealing with create model object and just want to use `TemplateView` and `FormMixin` to manage forms that are not related with the actual model, yo need to understand that this combination doesn't have a `POST`method implementation.

I you really want to achieve this with CBV you have to define your form as the following:

```
class ProjectDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView, ProcessFormView):
    #Your code here

   def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can use either `post` or `form_valid` method to manage the submit action.

Which do the trick is `ProcessFormView` that will allow you `POST` methods in your view.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is:

```
success_url =  reverse_lazy(your_path)
```

You also need to import `reverse_lazy` from `django.urls` like so:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```